# Webservice and Android App linking

Tags: php, android, web-services

I have been given a task to maintain an APP and web service developed by Ex colleague.

Looking at the APP code. When checking the API for connectivity between APP and Server I figured out the URL used is not direct link. I don't see any php file.

He has used Volley to connect the API on our server in AWS.

Say for example to login the URL is just: **http://mycompanydomain/mainfolder/login** - There is no .php file.

To connect using volley he is using the following:

```
 new VolleyRequest(Login.this).objectRequest("Please wait.. Logging In...", Constants.loginUrl, object, new VolleyRequest.VolleyCallBack() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(JSONObject object) 
              try {
                    if(object.getString("status").equalsIgnoreCase("success"))
                    {
                        if(object.getString("type").equalsIgnoreCase("shop"))
                        {
                           //LOGIN TO MY SHOP
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //LOGIN TO FACTORY
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        //USERNAME NOT VALID
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

How do I figure out the php file linked to this? I am unable connect to my ex. colleague to get some KT.

Can somebody help me on this? I am stuck here?

Thanks!

Comment: if one has used any frameworks or `htaccess` rules while creating APIs then there can be URLs without a '.php' extension.. a `.php` extension is not necessary in the URL

Comment: @NishantSolanki - Yes he has used laravel framework.  How do I figure out which file is it connected to? I don't see anything called login inside the mainfolder.

Comment: Check file `app\routes.php` or `app\http\routes.php` you will find a `login` route defined there.. Which will indicate which functions is called.. You will probably need someone who has knowledge about laravel

Comment: You will see something like `Route::get('login', function()........` OR ``Route::post('login', function()........`` in the `routes.php` file